# Recursively read folders and executes command on each of them if a file exists in that folder

Tags: bash, shell

I have this command which is fully functional and really like it.

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && ../Process.sh); done
```

It goes through all the subfolders and runs the Process.sh inside each folder.

What I need is, it just run the `Process.sh` if the "kill_by_pid" file exists in the folder. Unless, if the "kill_by_pid" does not exist in that specific folder, the folder be skipped and it just move to the next folder.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `find` and `execdir`, for example:

```
find . -type f -name "kill_by_pid" -execdir ../Process.sh \;
```

This will only call the `Process.sh` the script on the parent directory where the file `kill_by_pid` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for d in ./*/ ;
  do 
  if [ -f "$d"/kill_by_pid ]; then 
    (cd "$d" && ../Process.sh);
  fi
done
```

Comment: I have got this error:  syntax error at line 2: `if' unexpected

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```
for f in ./*/kill_by_pid; do
    pushd -- "${f#/*}"
    ../Process.sh
    popd
done
```

This finds each `kill_by_pid` file, then determines the name of the directory that contains it. (Using `pushd`/`popd` is just to demonstrate
a way of changing and restoring the current directory that doesn't require a subshell, in the event `Process.sh` needs to execute in the current shell session.)